# Rails bulk update all with NOT IN condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to perform an update_all to flag as inactive all rows that are not satisfying a condition

```
huge_array = ['A', 'B', ...]
Item.where(profile: profile).where.not(sku: huge_array).update_all(active: false)
```

but Array is too big (300K) and PG query timeouts (>120s).

I cannot use `huge_array.each_slice(1000)` otherwise it excludes all other rows at each step.

I found this alternative, but it loads all records in memory, and it's too much

```
  huge_array = ['A', 'B', ...]
  Item.where(profile: profile).where(active: true).find_in_batches do |enabled_records| 
    
    # DB Records that not contains an enabled SKU
    not_expected = enabled_records.select{|i| enabled_skus.exclude?(i.sku)}
    not_expected_ids = not_expected.pluck(:id)
    
    # Flag all not expected as inactive
    Item.where(profile: profile, active: true, id: not_expected_ids).update_all(active: false)
 
  end
```

How can I execute this with fewer query / less memory ?

Comment: Is there an index on the `sku` column? What is the ratio of SKUs in `huge_array` to all possible SKU codes in that table?

Comment: SKU is not indexed. Ratio is very low (1%).

Comment: Where does huge_array come from? Could this be done with a subquery?

Comment: huge_array does not come from a query. External API.

Comment: Is this something you have to do more often? Then I would suggest adding an index. If this is just a one-time job, why not run plain SQL without Rails involved?

Comment: It’s done periodically. It could the problem be the SQL is too long? The array of “NOT IN (..) is 300K values long

Comment: Here's my idea :). Add a new flag column called `incoming_active_status`. Before each process update it to `false` for all items. Then loop `huge_array` and update `incoming_active_status = true` because those need to be active, right? After the loop finishes, update the active column to false just for those with incoming_active_status = false. Empirically, it should work :)

Comment: What happens if you select the ids you want to update and then update them as two separate statements. `ids = Item.where(profile: profile).where.not(sku: huge_array).pluck(&:id)` Then do `Item.where(id: ids).update_all(active: false)`. That way your update statement isn't also doing the complex select.

Comment: You could try creating a temp table and insert the `huge_array` values into that table in batches, then join the temp table when updating instead of passing in all of the values at once.